# If $y<x$ is there a way to phrase it in terms of $y>$something?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

For instance I know $y<x$ implies $-y > -x$ but is there a way to phrase it in terms of $y>$ something (that does not itself contain $y$)?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are less than or equal to $0$, you can say $|y|>|x|$ but that's about it. Only given $y<x$, you can not say anything about what $y$ is greater than; only that $y$ is **not** greater than $x$.

Comment: From $-y > -x$ you could add $2y$ to both sides and get $y > 2y-x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

For each $x\in\Bbb R$ we have that the set $L_x:=\{y\,\mid\,y<x\}$ is *downward closed* meaning that $u<v\in L_x \,\implies\,u\in L_x$.

The other kind of sets, $G_x:=\{y\,\mid\,y>x\}$ don't have this property, because there exist $u,v\in\Bbb R$ such that $v>x>u$.